# regex : get value of a key-value pair format

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
"
key1: fkdfjdkfkdfjkdfkjdkfjdfkjdfkdjfkdjfkdfjkdfdkfjkdf
key2: dskfjdfjdkfkjdfkdjfkdfjdfkdfkdkjfkdfjkdf
key3: sdfsdfasdfadfs
asdfadsfsdfasdfadsfdf
key4: sdfjdsfhhdjfhsdjfsdfh
skdfjdsjkfjds
"
```

What would be a valid regex to capture only the values of the keys?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

The following regular expression solves your problem, providing you are using a PCRE engine:

```
/(?:key\d+: )(.*?)(?=\nkey\d:|$)/gs
```

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/1M7UZd/2)

Explanation:

- **(?:key\d+: )** - Matches the key.
- **(.*?)** - Captures the value.
- **(?=\nkey\d:|$)** - Stops capturing the value when the next key or the end of the string is found.
- **gs** flags - Global flag enables multiple captures, and single line flag enables the dot operator to match new lines in the values.